# RDP screen goes black after successful remote login

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, remote-desktop-services

We have a Windows 2012 R2 Server that was working perfectly, about month ago, when the administrator tries to connect remotely to the server he gets the login prompt, he enters his credentials but then the screen goes black.

The disks on the server still accessible and the Apps still running successfully.

Comment: Hmm, I had something similar yet on a Windows 10 machine recently. After a restart it was OK again. Might have been some (partially installed) update.

Comment: Exactly!!  after a restart everything works fine for a while.